# Vue.js 2.x Passing function to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to render the same component several times with different information and when someone selects something it should load a function in the main Vue instance.

Until now I wasn't able to pass a dynamic function as a property like `@change="onchange"`:

> **[Vue warn]:** Invalid handler for event "change": got undefined
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources\assets\js\components\GeographyField.vue

***The component:***

```
<template>
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <label :for="name" class="control-label" v-html="label"></label>
        <select class="form-control" :name="name" :id="name" :model="_default" :disabled="disabled" @change="onchange">
            <option :value="0" v-html="placeholder"></option>
            <option v-for="object in collection" :value="object.id">{{ object.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: {
            label: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Options'
            },
            _default: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            disabled: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            placeholder: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Choose an option'
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            collection: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            },
            onchange: {

            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

***The rendering:***

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Country -->
    <geography-field
            label="Pa&iacute;s"
            :_default="selectedCountry"
            placeholder="Choose a country"
            name="country"
            :collection="countries"
            :onchange="selectCountry()"
    ></geography-field>
    <!-- Department -->
    <geography-field
            label="Departamento"
            :_default="selectedDepartment"
            :disabled="selectedCountry < 1"
            placeholder="Choose a department"
            name="department"
            :collection="departments"
            :onchange="selectDepartment()"
    ></geography-field>
    <!-- Location -->
    <geography-field
            label="Localidades"
            :_default="selectedLocation"
            :disabled="selectedDepartment < 1"
            placeholder="Choose a location"
            name="location"
            :collection="localities"
            :onchange="selectLocation()"
    ></geography-field>
    <!-- Zone -->
    <geography-field
            label="Zonas"
            :_default="selectedZone"
            :disabled="selectedLocation < 1"
            placeholder="Choose a zone"
            name="zone"
            :collection="zones"
    ></geography-field>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Including `selectCountry()`:

```
selectCountry: function() {
        if(this.selectedCountry < 1) { return; }
        axios.get('/get_country/' + this.selectedCountry)
            .then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;
                if(data.departments.length > 0) {
                    var departments = [];
                    $.each(data.departments, function (index, value) {
                        departments.push(value);
                    });
                    app.departments = departments;
                }
            });
    },
```

How I should do to pass a function to the component properly? Any suggestions are appreciated

**Edit 2:** Something I might cleared up is that the components are being rendered well. Just in case I will add the component registration:

```
Vue.component('geography-field', require('./components/GeographyField'));
...
const app = new Vue({
```

Comment: The methods are all defined in `new Vue({ ... methods: { ... } ..}` or in a parent component?

Comment: @btl, the methods `selectCountry()`, `selectDepartment()` and `selectLocation()` are defined in a parent element on **app.js^*, There is where I register the component.

Comment: Can you include the `app.js` code. Might be helpful

Comment: I edited the question to include one function as an example, because the file it's too long to be include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass a function as a prop to the component, you need to strip off the trailing parentheses of the function name. Otherwise, Vue will evaluate the function. For example:

```
<geography-field
  label="Pa&iacute;s"
  :_default="selectedCountry"
  placeholder="Choose a country"
  name="country"
  :collection="countries"
  :onchange="selectCountry" // strip off the parentheses
></geography-field>
```

---

But, I would also suggest you use `$emit` instead of passing a function. You can do that like so:

**The component definition:**

```
<template>
  <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
    <label :for="name" class="control-label" v-html="label"></label>
    <select class="form-control" :name="name" :id="name" :model="_default" :disabled="disabled" @change="onchange">
      <option :value="0" v-html="placeholder"></option>
      <option v-for="object in collection" :value="object.id">{{ object.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  props: {
    label: { type: String, default: 'Options' },
    _default: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    disabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    placeholder: { type: String, default: 'Choose an option' },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    collection: { type: Array, required: true }
  },
  methods: {
    onchange() {
      this.$emit("onchange"); 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**The component tag in the parent scope:**

```
<geography-field
  label="Pa&iacute;s"
  :_default="selectedCountry"
  placeholder="Choose a country"
  name="country"
  :collection="countries"
  @onchange="selectCountry" // use @
></geography-field>
```

Comment: @JacobGoh it is correct if you are emitting an `onchange` event, like wang suggests. +1 for this answer since it is follows the props down, events up convention. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components

Comment: sorry.. my bad.

Comment: I marked it as correct, but still the parent element `selectedCountry` is not being altered

Comment: @Maramal most likely because you have `:model="_default"` instead of `v-model="_default"` on the `<select>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I've checked this after a few tests. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

e.g. 
`:onchange="selectCountry"`

Don't put `()` when you pass the function. It will trigger the function execution and whatever the function return will be pass into `onchange`.

Comment: I am still getting same error in the developer console

Comment: to prove the point: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/WMOzRO . You gotta check all the props you pass as function

Comment: sorry, I got the answer but not the comment. You are not doing whatever you said in the answer. In fact, you are doing exactly what I did, but instead of handling a function you just passed it as property.

Comment: i was just trying to show you why you should not add `()`. This is wrong: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/WMOzRO?editors=1010 . This is right: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/wyemjq?editors=1010

Comment: @ not : should be before the onchange